# python resampling from two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

have two data frames

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [10, 47, 58, 68, 75, 80],
                       'y': [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'x': [45, 55, 66, 69, 79, 82], 'y': [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5]})
```

**df1**

```
x   y
10  10
47  9
58  8
68  7
75  6
80  5
```

**df2**

```
x   y
45  10
55  9
66  8
69  7
79  6
82  5
```

I want to interpolate between them and generate a new data frame with a sampling rate of N. Assume N=3 for this example.

The desired output is

```
x          y
10         10
27.5       10
45         10
...
75         6
77         6
79         6
80         5
81         5
82         5
```

How can I use my data frames to create the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using numpy, this solution will give you your desired output:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

N = 3

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [10, 47, 58, 68, 75, 80],
                   'y': [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'x': [45, 55, 66, 69, 79, 82], 'y': [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5]})

new_x = np.array([np.linspace(i, j, N) for i, j in zip(df['x'], df2['x'])]).flatten()
new_y = df['y'].loc[np.repeat(df.index.values, N)]

final_df = pd.DataFrame({'x': new_x, 'y': new_y})

print(final_df)
```

**Output**

```
       x   y
0   10.0  10
1   27.5  10
2   45.0  10
3   47.0   9
...
15  80.0   5
16  81.0   5
17  82.0   5
```